# How to remove current playlist and add new playlist in jPlayer with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jplayer, playlist, audio-player

I have multiple window with multiple artist on each window and one play button. If we click on the play button I play the song using jPlayer skin. Now suppose user is on first screen and clicked play, songs start playing and i can see the playlist as well. But user toggle to next screen and there we have another set of playlist and if the user click play button there, what i want is to remove the previous playlist and load the songs of current playlist.

Here is what i have done:

```
var myPlayList;
$("#play").on("click",function(){
    jplayercall(SongsList);
});

function jplayercall(SongsList){
    var jplayerId = "";
    var jcontainer = "";

    var jplayerId = $("#jquery_jplayer_1");
    var jcontainer = "#jp_container_1";

    myPlaylist=new jPlayerPlaylist({
      jPlayer: jplayerId,
      cssSelectorAncestor: jcontainer
    },track_inside,
    {
        playlistOptions: { autoPlay:true},
        swfPath: "jplayer",
        supplied: "m4a",
        wmode: "window",
        useStateClassSkin: true,
        autoBlur: false,
        smoothPlayBar: true,
        keyEnabled: true
    });    
}
```

Everytime it loads and play first playlist properly but when selected second and click to play, playlist disappear and but keep singing songs from first playlist and it doesn't load the second playlist.